# Mocking the UnitOfWorkManager.Current in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, aspnetboilerplate

When unit testing, the system cannot resolve `UnitOfWorkManager.Current` (nullreference exception). The `_unitOfWorkManager` is of type: `IUnitOfWorkManager`, and injected via DI.

I'm testing the following web api code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Subscription(SubscriptionInputDto model)
{
    if (!await VendorHasAccess(model.OrganizationId))
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

    var input = new Subscription
    {
        ...
    };

    var data = await _subscriptionRepository.InsertAsync(input);

    await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(data.MapTo<SubscriptionDto>());
}
```

…with the following unit test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Create_New_Subscription()
{
    //Arrange
    var organization = await UsingDbContextAsync(async context => await context.VendorOrganizations.FirstOrDefaultAsync());
    var input = new SubscriptionInputDto { OrganizationId = organization.Id };

    //Act
    var actionResult = await _vendorController.Subscription(input);
    var response = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<SubscriptionDto>;

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(response);
    Assert.Equal(organization.Id, response.Content.OrganizationId);
}
```

I cannot figure out, or find any documentation on, how to resolve the `UnitOfWorkManager.Current` so that it doesn't fail for the unit test. 
The web API code itself works in production.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller method `virtual`.

See: [UnitOfWork Attribute Restrictions](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#DocUowRestrictions)

> You can use UnitOfWork attribute for:
>
> - All public virtual methods for self injected classes (Like MVC Controllers and Web API Controllers).

**Update**

If beginning a unit of work explicitly in your test is a reasonable resolution:

```
using (var unitOfWork = Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>().Begin())
{
    // ...
    unitOfWork.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if reasonable, but it seems to have solved the problem. :-) Thanks a bunch for your help!